# React setting input's value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've seen on many React tutorials regarding managing input values. The following pattern:

On Parent passing props to Input Component, handleInputText sets the state for anyValue:

```
<InputComponent textValue={this.state.anyValue} onInputtingText={this.handleInputText}/>
```

On Input Component, onEvent can be ==> onChange, onBlur...:

```
<input type='text' ref='inputRef' value={this.props.textValue} onEvent={this.handleInput}/>
```

InputComponent's handleInput:

```
handleInput(){
  this.setState(this.refs.inputRef.value)
}
```

Now my findings, I try to log it when the parents function when setting the state and it logs the initial. This are some tentative conclusions:

1. Whenever an event its trigger the value of the input is not the current value of the InputComponent. It is the value set on the parent to that value.
2. Both the input's value and this.props.textValue match on the second triggering of the event.

My question is, how do you handle this the react way? Or do you have to check this inside the handleInput function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes the same, I've just found that whenever I try to log the state value when set it returns the initial value. Why is so? I downloaded the React debugger and the state is set to the correct value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set state in `this.handleInputText` and call it inside `InputComponent`,

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { anyValue: '' };
  },

  handleInputtingText(value) {
    this.setState({ anyValue: value });
  },

  render() {
    return <div>
      <p>{ this.state.anyValue }</p>
      <InputComponent 
        textValue={ this.state.anyValue } 
        onInputtingText={ this.handleInputtingText } 
      />
    </div>
  }
});

var InputComponent = React.createClass({
  handleInput(e) {
    this.props.onInputtingText(e.target.value);
  },

  render: function() {
    return <input 
      type="text" 
      value={this.props.textValue} 
      onChange={ this.handleInput } 
    />;
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/36834/)